How to run celery worker in standalone mode
Having long running sporadic task being executed in AWS, we need to appropriately provision the instance and let it execute a single task and then exit in order to release resources.
How can we run celery worker to execute a single task on a queue and exit itself when completed without depleting any possible other tasks in the queue?
This command is still proceeding with other tasks if the others are queued:
celery -A tasks worker --concurrency=1 --max-tasks-per-child 1 --pool=solo

